# Score sytem for my java game

Tags: java, counter, scoring

I'm making a basic 2D side scroller for a college assignment. I'm looking to add a scoring system to it, to ultimately have a high score system. I'm having trouble getting the score to display, I have a block, that when the player touches it, they get + 1 score, I used:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score : " + Score);
```

This confirmed that the score was increasing properly. I would like to display the score in the top right of the window constantly, how would I go about it?

Other parts of the score code:

```
int Score = 0;

public String ScoreCount = "Score: " + Score;
```

**Edit:**
Thanks for the support, I'm still having trouble with getting it to display. I have:

    int Score = 0;
    public String ScoreCount = "Score: " + Score;

```
JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");
public void someoneScored()
{
scoreLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 50);
scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + Score);
}
```

My game has a black background (just a rectangle) would I need to change the colour of the JLabel? (I tried to change the colour of the background to white, and I still couldn't see it).

Answer (score 3):

Increment it, and update a `JLabel`.

**Example**

```
JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");


public void someoneScored()
{
    score++;

    scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
}
```

**Extra reading**

- A basic swing tutorial, like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) might be useful.
- Given you don't seem to know this, you should read the Java Naming Conventions for how to format your variable names properly. You can read them [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

**Edit**

If you want to position your `JLabel`, you can do this with the `setLocation` method. However, I like to set the size and the location all at once, and I use the `setBounds` method.

**Example**

```
scoreLabel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
```

To put this in the top left corner, your `x` and `y` will be Two very low numbers. Not `0`. Nothing looks worse than a label touching a corner of a window.

```
scoreLabel.setBounds(5, 5, width, height);
```

Comment: @Bathsheba Do you not like the space between the operand and the increment operator? :P

Comment: Old habits die hard. Nice +1 answer though.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, as you guessed, I'm a beginner and I really should of looked into some proper language tutorials before patching together a game. How would I go about displaying this in the corner? I'm sorry if this is rather annoying.

Comment: Don't worry buddy. Everyone starts somewhere. I'll edit in an example on how to specify where to put the label.

Comment: Edited main post, still having trouble with getting it to display, thanks for your help